# PowerBI: Split column in to separate columns

Tags: powerbi

I have a category multiselect field which i'm importing, which has multiple values separated by a comma:

> Agriculture, Microfinance, Peace Building

My primary instinct is to split each value in to a separate column using text functions, but i'm wondering if there's a better, easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found it! Opened Edit queries in the data view, right click the column, Split Column > By delimiter