# Replace comma with new line in power bi

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have value like `A,B,C` in report.

I need

```
A /n
B /n
C
```

"/n" new lines are not supported in power bi. I am new on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerBI: Split column in to separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832748/powerbi-split-column-in-to-separate-columns)

Comment: @ThomasStrub It doesnt because if we split , it duplicates other columns as well

Comment: Then you should change your question so this important information is given.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution for this is to use the inbuilt "advanced options" option under Replace values feature in Power Query. This solution is provided by [Seth in Power BI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Replace-carriage-return-in-dataset/m-p/24900).

Steps to follow (Screenshot below):

1. In the Data section, click "Edit Queries" in the ribbon.
2. Select the table you want, and right click the column header
3. Select "Replace Values", click in the "Value To Find"
4. Select "Advanced Options" check "Replace using special characters"
5. Select "Insert special character"
6. Click "**Carriage Return**" or "**Line Feed**" and the respective shot-form should show in your values section
7. Cut that short-form and paste it in "Replace with" field
8. Enter "," in the values section
9. Click OK
10. Close and Apply

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this and I noted that it's not "Carriage Return or Line Feed" it's "Carriage Return and Line Feed".  When I did this, it did not replace anything.  When I split the step into two parts (e.g. one step for carriage return and another step for line feed) it worked fine.  Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: What I meant by "or" is that they are different options available. Not that it replaces this or that in one step. But you can achieve the "or" result by editing the M language. I don't think it can be done using the UI. If you want to use the UI, you would need to split the steps into two parts like you did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SUBSTITUTE function to swap out commas for line breaks. Power BI will let you just type out the linebreak - though I think you have to use ALT-RETURN in the DAX function editor.

> lineBreaks = SUBSTITUTE([myCol], ",", "
>   ")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split Column By Delimiter` to split the values into separate rows. Lets say you have a table like this:

[image]

Click `Edit queries` to open `Power Query Editor`, select the column you want to split and click `Split Column` -> `By Delimeter`:

[image]

Make sure the delimiter is correct, and `Rows` is selected in `Split into`:

[image]

This will convert the table into this:

[image]

Which is pretty much what you ask for.